# Class based view helper does not output captured HTML as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I am trying to create a set of view helpers for a project I am working in and as they share a lot of common code, for better or worse, I am trying to take an object oriented approach. However, I am having problems when I try to capture and render HTML.

Instead of rendering the HTML within the tag, it will render it before the tag and also render it as a string within the tag.

I want to understand why there are differences in the behaviour and what I can do to fix it (if it is even possible to)

**Example 1: working functional approach**

I have the following helper:

```rb
# application_helper.rb

def my_helper(summary_text, &block)
  tag.details do
    concat(tag.summary(tag.span(summary_text)))
    concat(tag.div(&block))
  end
end
```

In my html.erb file I have:

```html
<%= my_helper('Summary text') do %>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

This will render:

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <span>
      Summary text
    </span>
  </summary>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</details>
```

**Example 2: non-working Object Oriented approach**

In my helper file I have defined the class:

```rb
# helpers/my_helper.rb

require 'action_view'

class MyHelper
  include ActionView::Context
  include ActionView::Helpers

  attr_reader :summary_text

  def initialize(summary_text)
    @summary_text = summary_text
  end

  def render(&block)
    tag.details do
      concat(tag.summary(tag.span(summary_text)))
      concat(tag.div(&block))
    end
  end
end
```

And in my application helper I have:

```rb
# application_helper.rb

def my_helper(summary_text, &block)
  MyHelper.new(summary_text).render(&block)
end
```

In my html.erb file I have:

```html
<%= my_helper('Summary text') do %>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

This will render:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<details>
  <summary>
    <span>
      Summary text
    </span>
  </summary>
  <div>
    &lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Item 1&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Item 2&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Item 3&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
  </div>
</details>
```

I would expect the Object Oriented approach to have the same result as the functional based approach.

I've had a try at debugging this in the Rails code and if I were to have a guess I think it's something to do with the `output_buffer` and the OO helper not using the same one as the view, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do here is pass the view context into the builder/decorator/presenter/view compont/thingamajigger and call the methods on it instead:

```
# do not use require - the Rails component are already loaded through railties
# do not call this "Helper" - that will just make things more confusing.
class ListBuilder
  attr_reader :summary_text
  attr_reader :context
  delegate :tag, :concat, to: :context

  def initialize(summary_text, context:)
    @summary_text = summary_text
    @context = context
  end

  def render(&block)
    tag.details do
      concat(tag.summary(tag.span(summary_text)))
      concat(tag.div(&block))
    end
  end
end
```

```
def list_with_summary(summary_text, &block)
  ListBuilder.new(summary_text, context: self).render(&block)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this almost worked. I also needed to delegate `concat` to `context` too. Once I did that I got the result I expected. Can you add that to your answer and then I can accept it?

Comment: Ooopsie, yeah forgot about concat.